# What does the notation $T \in \mathcal L(\mathbb F^2)$ mean in the context of endomorphisms of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

In the book "*Linear Algebra as an Introduction to Abstract Mathematics*", Chapter 7 spends a good deal of time fleshing out the concepts (and associated theorems) of **Linear Operators** (in particular, linear operators that act on vector spaces over complex fields). From a little bit of internet searching, I believe this is more commonly referred to as an edomorphism. At any rate, the authors define their **Linear Operator** term as follows:

> *A linear map $T \in \mathcal L(V,V)$ is called a linear operator on $V$*

The authors introduce the associated matrix notation on a linear operator $T$ in the form of:

> $M(T) = A \in \mathbb F^{n \times n}$

where $M(T)$ is the book's notation for "*matrix of a linear transformation*", and the $\mathbb F^{n \times n}$ denotes a matrix whose coefficients (entries in the matrix) are taken from field $\mathbb F$ and is comprised of $n$ rows and $n$ columns (or, equivalently, the basis of $V$ is comprised of $n$ vectors...i.e. $\text{dim}(V) = n$).

---

At the very end of this chapter, on **Page 75**, the authors introduce a new notation: $T \in \mathcal L(\mathbb F^2)$. Unfortunately, this notation is not accompanied with an explanation...however, the authors still refer to $T$ as a **linear operator**.

So what exactly does $T \in \mathcal L(\mathbb F^2)$ denote?

The only thing I can think of is it is saying that $T \in \mathcal L(V,V)$ where $V$ is a vector space over a **2-dimensional field**, which they denote as $\mathbb F^2$ (for example, like $\mathbb C$)...but I can't be sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An endomorphism is a map from an object back to the same object.  So one only needs to specify one argument to $\mathcal{L}$.  That is,
$$  \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{F}^2) = \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{F}^2,\Bbb{F}^2)  \text{.}  $$